# check if input-hidden-field is empty OR not

Tags: php, input, hidden

one part of my form is an input-hidden-field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="dump" id="dump" value="">
```

in this hidden-field an array is saved,
now i wanted to ask you which is the best way to check if this array is empty or does the array contain value´s ?

here is what i did:

```
if($_POST["dump"] == "") {
    $arr = json_decode($_POST["dump"], true); 
    if(count($arr) == 0) {
    echo "no value´s";
        $url = "";
        header("Location:".$url);
        exit();
    }
}
```

what do you think of it? are there any other, maybe more secure way´s to do this?

greetings!!

Comment: So the hidden field contains raw JSON? Your code block for `$_POST["dump"] == ""` will only execute if nothing is passed...

Comment: yes it contains raw JSON :) so what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dump = $_POST['dump'];
if (!empty($dump)) {
    $arr = json_decode($dump, true);
    if (!empty($arr)) {
        // data is correct
    }//add else
}//add else
```

`empty()` will only be false (in this case) if `$arr` is an array with at least one element. Also it will be true if `json_decode` fails (will return "NULL"). You can never trust user input so should always check for its correctness!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [PHP empty() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

**PHP.net Reports:**

> Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE.
>
> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> "" (an empty string)
>
> 0 (0 as an integer)
>
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
>
> "0" (0 as a string)
>
> NULL
>
> FALSE
>
> array() (an empty array)
>
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

It checks for lot of cases in which a var can be empty or not.

So you may want to use

```
if(empty($var)){ 
    // Yes, really empty
} else {
    // Not empty at all
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok this works fine, is it ok? :

```
if(empty($_POST["dump"])) {
    $arr = json_decode($_POST["dump"], true); 
    if(count($arr) == 0) {
        $url = "http://test80948.test-account.com/tweetmilliono/test.php";
        header("Location:".$url);
        exit();
    }
}
```